# Parse error in Faker for Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5, faker

```
I use "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.5"



<?php
    use Faker\Factory as Faker; use Illuminate\Database\Seeder; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; use Gopro\Served;
    class ServedTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run()  
    {  
        $faker = Faker::create();
        foreach(range(1,20) as $index)  
        {  
            DB::table('server')->insert([  
                'name' => str_replace('.', '_', $faker->unique()->name),  
                'location' => $faker->city,  
                'happytyp_id' => $faker->biasedNumberBetween($min = 1, $max = 8, $function = 'sqrt'),  
                'operatingsystem' => $faker->randomElement($array = array ('Windows 8.1','Windows RT','Windows Server 2012','Windows 7', 'Windows Vista', 'Unix V7', 'AIX', 'A/UX', 'Solaris'),
                'version' => strval($faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 4))
            ]);  
        }
    }
    }
```

PHP Parse error:

```
parse error in /Gopro/database/seeds/ServeTableSeeder.php on line 22
And I get the following error: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  parse error
```

My models and my tables exist and my Databaseseeder.php has on top:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Gopro\Typ;
use Gopro\Served;
```

I have done composer dump-autoload. Can someone help me?

I also noticed that there is both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
<?php
use Faker\Factory as Faker; use Illuminate\Database\Seeder; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; use Gopro\Served;
class ServedTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();
        foreach(range(1,20) as $index)
        {
            DB::table('server')->insert([
                'name' => str_replace('.', '_', $faker->unique()->name),
                'location' => $faker->city,
                'happytyp_id' => $faker->biasedNumberBetween($min = 1, $max = 8, $function = 'sqrt'),
                'operatingsystem' => $faker->randomElement(array('Windows 8.1','Windows RT','Windows Server 2012','Windows 7', 'Windows Vista', 'Unix V7', 'AIX', 'A/UX', 'Solaris')),
        //                                                 ^ removed redundant variable declaration                                                You missed a closing parenthesis ^
                'version' => strval($faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 4))
            ]);  
        }
    }
}
```